# C# WCF Mirroring

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am working on a enterprise system that has a legacy green screen system talking to a WCF Service service layer hosted in IIS.
I would like to implement a mirroring function so assist with testing releases that have passed UAT.

In essence I would like to run the new version of test release side by side with the live release. Every WCF request received would be sent to both the live WCF Service and the Test WCF Service. We could then run a report at a later date to compare results between the two systems.

The system making the call cannot be changed and can only support a single endpoint so ideally some solution that takes a request, forwards it on then continues and returns the results would be ideal.
Does anybody have any idea how I could accomplish this without hopefully causing massive performance issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can leverage [WCF Routing services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

1. Write new WCF service that has all the same data and operation contracts as the live system (proxy service)
2. Proxy serving would then send the requests to both the live and system under test, compare the answers, and reports deviations

As the proxy service really won't be doing much work you hopefully won't see a performance degradation assuming calls to live and test system are parallelized.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry, left off the 3rd step.  Point the client to the new proxy WCF service.  Now the client calls the proxy, proxy forwards calls to both live WCF service and WCF service under test, and returns to the client the results of calls to live service and generates reports of any discrepancies between the results of the live and test systems.